# Why does my Perl script hang while trying to connect to a database using DBI?

Tags: mysql, perl, runtime-error, dbi

My connect string is:

```
use strict;
use DBI;

my $dbh = DBI->connect("DBI:mysql:database=[DB];host=[HOST]","[USERNAME]", "[PASSWORD]",{'RaiseError' => 1});
```

When I run the script, nothing happens - it doesn't show any errors, and I have to `CTRL+C`to break the operation.

- Perl v5.10.1
- DBI version 1.52
- DBD::mysql version 3.0007
- MySQL - version?

Any ideas what's going on here?

Comment: It's going to take a lot more information to diagnose your problem.  Just off the top of my head.  what's your perl version?  What's your DBI version?  What's your database server specs?  etc.  I'm sure you could also come up with a lot more relevant information as well.

Comment: Perl 5.10.1 and the latest DBI... what do you mean by server specs? It's MySQL - what else would you need to know?

Comment: What happens if you append `mysql_connect_timeout=5` (or similar) to the DSN?

Comment: @pilcrow - I'm not sure how to do that - can you give me code sample?

Comment: I don't necessarily need to know all your server specs (I don't know what's wrong).  However, this is a relatively simply operation, so always include all information about the environment.  I'll edit the question to show where to include version information.

Comment: Can you connect from the command line using the MySQL client?

Comment: yeah i can connect to the database via ssh and run any commands fine

Comment: How is SSH involved? Are you ssh'ing to a different machine where the MySQL database is and running the MySQL command line client there? Or using SSH for port forwarding?

Comment: Can you connect to the database using the mysql client on the same machine where you run the script?

Comment: I'm ssh'ing to another server and i connect to it there - i use the "hostname" command to plug in the [HOST] i had in the above coe

Comment: You need to make sure that you can connect to the database from the machine where the script is being run. If you can't connect to it directly (i.e. without SSH) then you have to look into why that is.

Comment: I dont have the client, im just connect with a terminal

Comment: Then get the client, Mysql Workbench, or some other tool which you can use to test the connectivity.

Comment: @CheeseConQueso [Examples for mysql_connect_timeout](https://www.google.com/search?q=mysql_connect_timeout+dbi+perl&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a&channel=fflb)

Comment: DBD::mysql version 3.0007 is really ancient.

Comment: I figured it out finally... when i was in the server i had to use localhost sshtupid

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you specify the detailed string for the parameters about the connect() method?
Make sure your database is running ok.
Like shown below:

```
use strict;
use DBI;
my $user = "root";
my $passwd = "123456";
my $data_source = "dbi:mysql:test_db";
my $dbh = DBI->connect($data_source,$user,$passwd, {RaiseError => 1})
                or die "Can't connect to $data_source: $DBI::errstr";
```

Comment: I have them in the actual script, but kept them off this site for security reasons... thanks anyway

Answer (score -1):

you  need to replace the DB,HOST, USERNAME and PASSWORD with actual values for your local setup. first of all make sure you can connect to the mysql from command line with those credentials

Comment: I appreciate your help, but I just left those out for security reasons haha... thanks anyway